# How to sync voice memos with itunes over air

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, voice-memo

How can I sync my voice memos on iphone with my macbook over air?
It works with cable but I want to work over air. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with "over the air" you mean iCloud I'm sorry but it's not possible. The only way is to use a third party application that use iCloud to store the memos, like [this](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/voice-recorder-hd-per-registrazioni/id373045717?mt=8). Instead if you mean WiFi it is possible to do that using iTunes and the normal WiFi sync.